When I connect Pico and Pi4 via USB, what is the Max baud rate?
Usually, it is written as if up to 1,000,000 is possible. However, I learned examples of setting baud rate = 115200. Can I set it up faster than this?
I am using Pi4 and Pico The connection is USB-8pin.
connected by 115200bps

This is probably more appropriate for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

The max "baud"[1] (most likely not a correct term here)
depends on a lot of factors and whether you can maintain a steady state of these.
For starters, what comes up in my mind at writing:

processing power at both ends of the link
processing power of any converters involved
quality and length of the cabling
whether any link control is used (SW/3-wire XON/XOFF, HW RTS/CTS and similar)

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Speed for "baud", the remainder of the text in general.
[1] "baud" refers to the number of signal changes on the transmission line. If you happen to have ANY type of modulation involved, baudrate and transmission rate will not be the same. e.g. old 9600bps modems uses 2400 baud.
